# Vuetify override default prop value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there any way to change default value of a prop in a vuetify component? 
For example lets say we have a component like `v-btn`. 
This component has many props, One of them like `outlined` with default value of `false`.

Lets say i want is to change this default value to `true` forever in my application. Is there any way?

Comment: Any reason not to create custom components?

Comment: @Txema Cannot edit a current project with too many files and codes. find all v-btn components and replace them with another component.  also it would be nice to set some defaults before starting to work with vuetify. to make the code volume smaller

Comment: Same issue, I'd like to see all my input fields have the "filled" and "persistent-hint" props by default instead of having to add it for every instance. And I'd prefer to do this without having to make a custom components again

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do that at the top of my app's entry point (before any Vue component creation).

```
/** 
 * [required imports]
 * (you must somehow import VBtn component separately)
 */

Vue.use(Vuetify);
VBtn.options.props.outlined.default = true;
```

But this practice is called monkey patching and not encouraged to use, consider to use inheritance instead.

In my case I was trying to get component from `Vue.options.components['VBtn']` but [it didn't work](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/list-registered-vue-components/7556/8?u=d9k).

[So I monkey patched](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/list-registered-vue-components/7556/13?u=d9k) vue library too:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

export const vueComponentsImported: any = {};
export const vueComponentFnDefault = Vue.component.bind(Vue);

/** @see node_modules/vue/src/core/global-api/assets.js */
export const vueComponentFnModded = (id, component) => {
  vueComponentsImported[id] = component;
  return vueComponentFnDefault(id, component);
};

Vue.component = vueComponentFnModded;

Vue.use(Vuetify);

let VBtn = vueComponentsImported['VBtn'];
if (VBtn) {
  VBtn.options.props.outlined.default = true;
}
```

(please feel free to edit this code if it doesn't work, I have much more lines in my app)

Comment: Yeah the best way to default it would be to create a custom wrapper component that would be used to have the props default values overridden

Answer (score -4):

It doesn't make sense to do this，you could just replace `'<v-btn'` with `'<v-btn outlined'`.

Comment: He doesn't want to write the property "outlined" on every declaration but just in the app configuration if possible. I am interested if there is a solution

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. if so, The best way I can think of is to define a component and set all the required styles, then inherit this component where you need to use it.